# need a update query by joining 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help to find out the possible solution. i stucked in this query.

table 1 - `hs_hr_employee`

- emp_number
- employee_id
- emp_lastname
- joined_date

Table 2 -  `ohrm_leave_entitlement`

- emp_number
- no_of_days    decimal(19,15)
- days_used     decimal(8,4)
- days_used
- leave_type_id

i need to join these table and get joined date and update  with 0.5 addition. if difference( Current dt- Dt. of Joining) >10.

here is my query

```
 UPDATE ohrm_leave_entitlement
 SET no_of_days = no_of_days + 0.5
 WHERE 
 ( 
     ohrm_leave_entitlement.emp_number = hs_hr_employee.emp_number
     AND 
     hs_hr_employee.joined_date < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
     AND
     leave_type_id=2
 )
```

But its not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  ohrm_leave_entitlement a
        INNER JOIN hs_hr_employee b
            ON a.emp_number = b.emp_number
SET     a.leave_type_id = a.leave_type_id + 0.5
WHERE   DATEDIFF(NOW(), b.joined_date) > 10
```

- [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
UPDATE ohrm_leave_entitlement , hs_hr_employee
SET ohrm_leave_entitlement.leave_type_id = ohrm_leave_entitlement.leave_type_id + 0.5
WHERE ohrm_leave_entitlement.emp_number = hs_hr_employee.emp_number
AND hs_hr_employee.joined_date < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
   UPDATE ohrm_leave_entitlement
    SET leave_type_id = leave_type_id + 0.5
    WHERE  
     ohrm_leave_entitlement.emp_number IN (SELECT  hs_hr_employee.emp_number FROM hs_hr_employee 
    WHERE  hs_hr_employee.joined_date < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
```